# Caching downloaded browser in Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, caching, jenkins-declarative-pipeline, mounted-volumes

Hi I have a project with e2e tests. The goal is to run these tests in jenkins many times. Before actuall running I have to install every time chrome browser. I mean exactly commands in JenkinsFile:

```
 sh 'wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb'
 sh 'apt-get update && apt-get install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb'
```

In case when I will run this pipeline let's say 30 times in the minute then the browser will be downloaded 30 times from scratch. I would like to cache this browser. As I know I can achieve that with volumes.

My whole JenkinsFile with declarative syntax is:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
            docker {
                registryCredentialsId 'dockerhub-read'
                image 'node:17.3-buster'
                args '-v $HOME/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb:/root/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb'
                reuseNode true
            }
    }
    parameters {
            string(name: 'X_VAULT_TOKEN', defaultValue: '', description: 'Token for connection with Vault')
            string(name: 'SUITE_ACCOUNT', defaultValue: '', description: 'Account on which scenario/scenarios will be executed')
            string(name: 'Scenario', defaultValue: '', description: 'Scenario for execution')
            choice(name: 'Environment', choices:
            ['latest', 'sprint', 'production (EU1)', 'production (EU3)', 'production (US2)', 'production (US8)', 'production (AU3)'],
            description: 'Environment for tests')
    }
    options {
            disableConcurrentBuilds()
    }
    stages {
        stage("Initialize") {
            steps {
                sh 'wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb'
                sh 'apt-get update && apt-get install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb'
                sh 'yarn install'
                sh "./init.sh ${params.Environment} ${params.X_VAULT_TOKEN} ${params.SUITE_ACCOUNT}"
            }
        }
        stage("Run Feature tests") {
            steps {
                     echo 'Running scenario'
                     sh 'yarn --version'
                     sh 'node --version'
                     sh """yarn test --tags "@${params.Scenario}" """
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to add in docker section:

```
args '-v $HOME/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb:/root/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb'
```

based on section **Caching data for containers** in the article https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/

This dosen't work. Browser downloads again and again. What's wrong?

Comment: The pipeline is executing in the workspace. Also, the workspace in the agent container is automatically mounted to the server workspace. You would need to preserve workspace between jobs, or download the package outside of the workspace and bind volume mount that directory.

Comment: I've added bash scripts in steps section which checks if file exists in localization $HOME/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb. It seems that browser in in workspace. Browser isn't downloaded again. How to explain that works?

Comment: @KrzysztofMichalski I think you might want to look into creating you own docker images if you have not done so already; This way you can offload the whole chrome downloading and installing (and maybe more) to the creation of that image.